# How to make Geany highlight smarty block comments?

Tags: linux, syntax-highlighting, geany

How to make Geany highlight smarty block comments ?

Smarty block comments are:

- start `{*`
- end `*}`

Thanks.

Comment: See my answer to [Geany comment block format](http://superuser.com/a/848997)